# frontend workflow - webpack, grunt, browserify?

Tags: webpack, gruntjs

I'm a front-end developer and I have been in the dilemma of what to learn and use(webpack,grunt ,gulp, browserify) in an big upcoming project.

I have been developing small projects without using any tool besides grunt but the workflow in grunt is isn't that efficient, specially when making changes, adding new elements and etc.

So i wanted to ask the seasoned front-end developers here on what is the best tool to use for a big projects in terms of frontend? Basically i will have to create the pages/themes then it will be sent to the backend developers to use it.

I have been looking to webpack however there are some inconsistency regards to webpack version and plugins i wanted to use. To make the story short all the plugins i need cannot work together due to some only works on certain version of webpack.

I hope someone can enlighten me with the best tool to use.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you can add what framework (or no framework) you intend to use, for example if you are going to use React, theres create-react-app that has Webpack built-in

Answer (score 1):

I've been in the same boat, so here's my story:

I started learning Gulp because at the time I knew JavaScript and Node, seeing as Gulp is mainly just an easy to follow Node application, this seemed like the reasonable choice. I looked into Grunt but I didn't have the right feeling with the config notation, I wanted more control.

I made different Gulp 'builders' that transpiled/compiled and minified assets for my personal and professional projects (scss to css, combine vendor scripts like jquery/bootstrap, compile es6 to es5 with Babel etc). All seemed fine, Gulp did what I needed it for and my Gulp builders did what they were made for.

### But then...

I found out about Webpack, started following some Webpack dev's on Twitter, started to read alot about it, followed the hype around it and fell in love. I started to learn Webpack but quickly realised it was way harder than I expected. It has a very different approach compared to Gulp or Grunt and to me it took a while to get even the basics down, it was a completely different way of thinking as to what I was used to with Gulp.

I made Webpack do what Gulp used to do for me, and it was a painful road to success.

Nevertheless it was worth learning, because I wouldn't wanna go back to my old Gulp setups (and wish I could migrate older projects to it).

### TL;DR

I don't know why I'm boring you with my little story: Give Webpack a try, it's worth it.

Comment: thanks for the input Milanzor, I really appreciate your story and your time for making the effort of telling me your insightful story. Will definitely go forward with webpack now.

Btw would you mind sharing your webpack.config.js and package.json? it would be a great help if i could see your amazing workflow structure and if its okay with you if i can use or take a pinch off it..

Thanks again Milanzor

Comment: Yeah, I can, I have some stuff on my github, github.com/milanzor/stein-boilerplate for example has some Webpack configuration that might help you on your way, next to that I'd learn the basics first, check out https://webpack.academy